# Which values can $k$ take, if $(k+6)(k-2)>0$

Tags: geometry, coordinate-systems

**Question:** Find the set of values of $k$ for which the line $y = kx - 4$ intersects the curve $y = x^2 - 2x$ at two distinct points.

I have pretty much solved this.

Considering both intersect, I equated both the equations and formed a single equation for which, I applied the condition discriminant is greater than zero. I ended up with this:

$$(k + 6)(k - 2) > 0.$$

However, I need to find the set of values. How do I represent the above answer as a set of values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you seem to struggle with some of the notation used in the other answers, I'll try to doe it a little differently.

Note that $(k+6)(k-2)=(k+2)^2-16$. So we solve:
$$(k+2)^2-16>0\\
(k+2)^2>16\\
\vert k+2 \vert>4.$$

Now $\vert k+2\vert > 4$ means that we have 
$$k+2<-4\;\;\vee \;\;4<k+2\\
k<-6\;\;\vee\;\; 2<k.$$

Comment: I got it. Thank you very much. I basically expand the solutions and put it into the format $(x + b)^2 + c$ and solve is it?

Comment: This is always possible for quadratic equations, yes.

Answer (score 3):

$$(k + 6)(k - 2) > 0$$

$2$ cases are possible here.

Case-$1$:

Both $k + 6>0$ and $k - 2>0$ $\implies k>2$

Case-$2$:

Both $k + 6<0$ and $k - 2<0$ $\implies k<-6$

So the required set of values is $$k \in \color{red}{(-\infty,-6)\cap(2,\infty)}$$

Comment: I did not understand case 1 and case 2. Why can't it be $k > -6$ and $k < 2$

Comment: I also did not understand what your set notation means (I have not learnt sets yet).

Comment: @HassanAlthaf Okay, firstly, if you take $k=0$ or any other $k$ which is greater than $-6$ and less than $2$, then your inequality won't be satisfied. Your inequality will be satisfied only when both terms $(k-2)$ and $(k+6)$ are positive or both are negative. Only then their product will be positive ($>o$). Get it?

Comment: @HassanAlthaf As for the set notations, $\in$ means "belongs to" and $()$ means an open interval, that is, $k$ will take all the values between the $2$ numbers mentioned in the $()$ **excluding** the $2$ numbers mentioned.

Comment: I still don't understand. Can you write down any steps or something to check?

Comment: @HassanAlthaf Exactly where do you want the steps??

Answer (score 0):

You can do it various ways; I'd default to intervals, but you can do set notation too:
$$
k \in (-\infty, -6)\cup (2, \infty)
$$
Note the open intervals here. Alternatively:
$$
\left\{ k: (k<-6) \vee (k>2) \right\}
$$

Comment: Is there any other way? I have not learnt sets yet.

Comment: How do I fix that formatting? I'm doing it on my phone so it's being a pain :(

Comment: I'm not sure but it was working a few seconds ago.

Comment: You can literally just write "all values less than -6, and all values greater than 2".

Answer (score 0):

The value will be greater than 0  only if 1) both the terms k+6 and k-2 are positive(greater than 0) 2) or both the terms are negative( less than 0) 
1) k+6>0.    k-2>0
.  k>-6      k>2 
.  -6<2  . Hence k>2.
2) k+6<0.    k-2<0
.  k<-6.   k<2
Hence k<-6
 therefore k belongs to (-infinity,-6)U(2, infinity)

(from your comments you have said you don't know sets . So here the round bracket means all real numbers between the two except the.and U means the union of all the numbers in the bracket.)